# what is the right way to implement observer in common service?

Tags: angular, service, observable

I have 2 components and common service to connect between them, I send data from the first component and get this data in the service but the second component not get this data.
first component:
init:

```
 constructor(private commonService: commonService) {}
```

and send the data like this:

```
this.commonService.notify(this.Index);
```

common service:

```
private source = new Subject<number>(0);
  public indexChanged$ = this.source.asObservable();
  constructor() {
  }

 public notify(n:number) {
    this.source.next(n);
 }
```

second componenet:

```
constructor(private commonService: commonService) {
    commonService.indexChanged$.subscribe(number  =>{
      console.log("number", number)
    });
```

I look [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service) and did the same, but never gets value.
thanks

*edit - I get the initial number at the second component but nothing after that

Comment: Subject does not hold any value, are you sure your values are emitted after second component is subscribed?

Comment: yes, the value sent from the UI after the user choose something, and both components are initialized already

Comment: I got it, you have `this.number`, just type `number` instead

Comment: thanks, I changed it but number still not gets any value

Comment: I have the last assumption, you added the service in providers in many places, and there are many instances of  commonService class(by the way, why it is written in camelCase and not in Pascal). So each component uses a different instance.

Comment: As Nikolai say: In which module you declare the service?. The two components are at time in the page (sorry if this last one is a silly question)?

Comment: you right, i moved the declartion to app.module instead to add it to the components, thanks a lot @Nikolai

Answer (score 0):

You could use BehaviorSubject.

BehaviorSubject holds value and initialize it, then you can call notify method and set new value.

common service:

```
 private source = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
 public indexChanged$ = this.source.asObservable();

 constructor() {
 }

 public notify(n:number) {
   this.source.next(n);
}
```

second component:

```
 constructor(private commonService: commonService) {
   commonService.indexChanged$.subscribe(number  =>{
     console.log("number", number)
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work, I saw the value sent to notify but not received in the second component